# Extending holidays after bad news

Tags: termination, personal-problems, holidays

I need an advice. I've received the bad news that my father has lost his job while I was in Italy for holidays. He hasn't told me yet, I know as my step-mother told me so, knowing that he wouldn't tell me otherwise. I need to go back to the UK so that I can go back to work tomorrow, and I'm feeling so not ready to do so. The ticket change would cost a lot, but I don't care too much.
Should I ask if I can extend my holidays for another three days to stay here a little while longer? I've been on holidays since yesterday. How can I go about asking that? Should I do it? I feel so bad either way, really confused not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't know. I feel that by going back home I would be abandoning him in some way. It's definitely something irrational, I probably just need someone to tell me "No, that would be stupid, just go back to work and find another way to figure things out".

Comment: Don't be so quick to accept an answer on this.  I would wait a few hours and see what you get.  Lots of knowledge on this site.

Comment: Asking whether it would make sense to spent time with your father after him losing his job (your own career aside) is unfortunately not a workplace issue and thus off topic, but might be on topic for [interpersonal.se]. But don't phrase it as if you want them to make the decision for you. Asking for leave is workplace related, but it's trivial - just ask, but it's *mildly* better if you phrase it as to say you'd be okay with them saying no.

Comment: The question you asked is "(how) can I ask to extend my leave last minute?". The question you accepted an answer for is "Should I?" and that's more of a personal one. You should probable rephrase this to the latter question though that's really off-topic here and it will probably end up getting your question closed. Bit of a catch-22 here I guess.

Comment: I would ask myself, would spending the extra money, and possibly damaging my own relationships at my work to spend 3 days there help as compared to staying in touch from the UK, staying employed, and having that money to help financially if it is needed later?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was going off the title but he's asking both questions I suppose.

Comment: Imagine if that puts a bad view on you at your work. Just now, your dad probably wants you to definitely keep your job. Maybe that is even a reason he did not tell you. You need to focus on your life so you can be able to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sorry your father lost his job. That sucks.

But... you're both adults. You shouldn't spend your life running around after him when something bad happens - you need to live your life, and he needs to live his without either of you leaning on the other too much.

If there were some specific action that you could do that *needed* you to be in Italy, that may be a different situation, but it doesn't sound like that's the case here, so to borrow from your own comment: "No, that would be stupid, just go back to work and find another way to figure things out." You can still help from the UK.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're right, even if that's so tough for me to accept right now. Needed to get that from someone else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your comment about not wanting to abandon him that your Father lives in Italy?

Sure, you could ask to extend a few days for a "family emergency" but with all due sympathies I'm not sure if most employers would consider this such an emergency (vs say serious illness, bereavement etc)

If you've got annual leave left and you know your employer is fairly laid back about short-notice leave requests you could always contact them and ask but I'd make it clear that you understand if it's not possible and be prepared for a "no"

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ask if I can extend my holidays for another three days to
>   stay here a little while longer?

No, definitely do not do that.  Although it is a very human thing to do, and how you feel is understandable I do not believe it will help.

Do not add to his stress by extending your holiday to your fathers already crap situation.  Go back home, go back to work, and **support your father as best you can via phone and Skype.**

If your father needs a break before seeking new employment offer to him to come **stay with you as a mini vacation/break** if this is possible ( *if you have the room* ).